# Notification auto cancel not working for Android lollipop

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I want to auto cancel my notification when user clicks on notification. The following code works good in all the devices except Android lollipop device. In  Lollipop device, notification goes only when user swipes it off.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void sendNotification(int id){

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("Jump to next screen")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;


    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);

   resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, 
                                    resultIntent, 0);
    //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // id, if there is a need to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

    Log.v(TAG, "Notification ID value " + id);

    //mNotificationManager.cancel(id);
}
```

What is missing in this code?

Comment: Even I see this issue. Were you able to find a work around? What i see is, its getting removed as and one any refresh happens in the notification center.

Comment: Following. I am stuck too. Looked all over SO but no resolution for this issue yet. I am currently running a timer and cancelling all notifications after the timer runs out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. My auto cancel still works on 5.0.2. Let me give you a portion of my code:

```
public static void notif(int id, String title, String text, Context context, Class activity) {
    // get an instance of the NotificationManager service
    if (mNotifyMgr == null)
        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent notifIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(notifIntent);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify following: 
setAutoCancel(true) -> setAutoCancel(false);
then on action activity do the following

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

if you want to set special condition you can set by

```
intent.putExtra("key", "value")
```